# Не устанавливает апп на девайс из xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3

Перестал устанавливать приложение на девайс из xcode, раньше все работало... Уже пересоздал сертификаты и по новой их закинул в проект, но все равно не получается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Удалить старый апп, перезагрузить девайс, удалить старый сертификаты из кейчейна (!), так же убедиться, что нету этой проблемы http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129362/certificates-problems-apple-wwdrca-certificate-signed-by-an-unknown-authorith

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689116/certificate-has-either-expired-or-has-been-revoked